# html5 aria role attribute for styling / js hooks?

Tags: html

I found few websites that use attribute `role` in place of `ids` for styling and js hooks.

Is this a good approach? What is the proper use of the `role` attribute?

My understanding is this: `classes` for styling, `ids` for js hooks, `role` for [WAI-ARIA](http://www.cfit.ie/news-and-commentary-archive/96-wai-aria-in-html5) but it seems the `role` can replace the `id`.

Here is an example:

```
<ul role="menu" class="menu">
  <li role="menuitem" aria-haspopup="false">New</li>
  <li role="menuitem" aria-haspopup="false">Open…</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Document structure roles help screen readers identify parts of static content easily, which can help better organize content for navigation.  You can javascript on any of classes, ids or roles, just depends on the use case for your widget.